Charged pendulum and a fixed point charge
!My set-up is the following: i have an iron bolt suspended on a string next to an electromagnet, of which I steadily increase the voltage and thereby the magnetic field. Supposing the force is linear with the magnetic field and dependent on the distance between the bolt and magnet. The exact dependence is what I seek, but assume that it is ~ $1/r^\alpha$ with $\alpha$ an undetermined constant. What is the relation between the deviation of the bolt ($sin(\theta)$) and the strength of the magnetic field?  The data seems to point to a cubic relationship ($sin(\theta)$ ~ $B ^3$) but I cant find why, any approximations ( even wild ones) are welcome.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
